# C++ Break out of a vector loop

Tags: c++, vector

I have a method in a class `LinkRepository`, I am checking for duplicate entries in the vector array `Datalinks`, which is a member of the class.  I loop through all the elements in the array to check in the new entry `Datalink* datalink` already exist in the array.  If so then don't add, just exit the loop.

```
void LinkRepository::SaveLink(Datalink* datalink) {
bool Exist = false;

for(vector<Datalink*>::iterator dl = Datalinks.begin(); dl != Datalinks.end(); ++dl)
{
     if((strstr((*dl)->ParentID, datalink->ParentID) != NULL) && (strstr((*dl)->ChildID,datalink->ChildID) != NULL))
     {
          Exist = true;

          dl = Datalinks.end();
     }
}

    if(!Exist)
    {
        Datalinks.push_back(datalink);
    }
};
```

My program seems to crash on the next loop of the statement `dl = Datalinks.end();`

I have no idea why it is crashing?

Comment: If you don't want duplicates, are you sure `std::vector` is the right choice? There are other data structures that prevent duplicates more efficiently, like `std::set` and `std::unordered_set`.

Comment: @FredOverflow do you maybe have sources I can look at to see which is the better one to use? I chose `std::vector` because I want a dynamic array, also I do the duplicate checking myself, because I have to look at the members of the `ParentID` and `ChildID` in the `Datalink` objects. Not use it `std::set1` or `std::unordered_set` can do this for me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Replace

```
dl = Datalinks.end();
```

With:

```
break;
```

To exit the loop

Here is a simple example to illustrate why your solution can't work:

```
int i = 0;
for (; i != 10; ++i)
{
    i = 10;
}
```

This loop will never end because i will be incremented to 11 before comparison `i != 10`

Comment: You can also change `dl = Datalinks.end();` to `dl = Datalinks.rbegin();`. That will set `dl` to one before `end`, so the increment will make it equal to `end`. Another way is to change the test from `dl != Datalinks.end()` to `dl >= Datalinks.end()`. There are many ways to fix it, but `break` is probably the best.

Comment: @Andrew This did the the trick, and your example explained well why it was not working, thanks.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: This breaks when reverse-iterators do not have the same type as [forward-]iterators and really relies on the container's implementation details rather than its abstractions.

Answer (score 4):

It is crashing because first you set the iterator to `Datalinks.end()` and then, upon leaving this iteration, the `for` loop itself increments the iterator, making an invalid operation.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(vector<Datalink*>::iterator dl = Datalinks.begin(); dl != Datalinks.end() && !Exist; ++dl)
{
     if((strstr((*dl)->ParentID, datalink->ParentID) != NULL) && (strstr((*dl)->ChildID,datalink->ChildID) != NULL))
     {
          Exist = true;
     }
}
```

Like everyone had said you are iterating one over. So, it's going into unwanted memory locations resulting in a seg fault eventually. You have to realize that the ++dl is happening at the end of the loop.

Also, using a break statement here is ridiculous. You already have a bool, make use of it.

Comment: Thanks for the alternative idea, just a question? Why do yo see the break statement here as being ridiculous?